# AWS: can't create code deploy application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I've created IAM Instance profile following this guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html

Then I'm trying to create CodeDeploy application and set this IAM instance profile, but it fails with message:

```
Cannot assume role provided.
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please review your trust policy once and if everything is fine then try updating and rebooting your instance once.

Hope it should work else you always have the ref below : 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_roles.html